# Pommettes == Butt?

Tags: vocabulaire, formulation-idiomatique

In MC Solaar's (really great) song, [La Belle et le Bad Boy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BVtFoLCcDw), he raps about the life of an outlaw.

> Risqué pour les pommettes, les mecs sortent des Baumettes

In English, people will use the word "butt" or "ass" to refer to a person in general. Like "Thanks for saving my ass."

In French, is "pommettes" (="cheekbones") commonly used in the same way?

Or is Solaar simply using pommettes because it rhymes with [Baumettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumettes_Prison)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**,

I don't think "pommettes" is used as an idiomatic way to refer to someone in the same way as english speakers may use "ass" (by several orders of magnitude).

I'm pretty sure your hunch is correct : MC Solaar uses "pommettes" for the rhyme.

That isn't very far-fetched : what cheekbones risk in this line is obviously receiving punches (or worse).